# How to added Basic Auth for Spring application?

Tags: java, spring, authentication

I have simple application on Spring Boot 3.2.0.
I have setup security.
My config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new MyUserDetailService();
  }

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return  daoAuthenticationProvider;
  }

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/health", "/api/v1/user/new").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated())
            .formLogin(AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer::permitAll)
            .build();
  }
}
```

I have added admin user. And I can get access to my endpoint via browser with credential which I have added

```
@GetMapping("/user")
public List<User> getAllUsers(){
    return userService.getAllUsers();
}
```

[image]

[image]
But how can I get the same result from postman? If I added the same credential into Basic Auth it doesn't work. The response is just the login form page
[image]

Comment: Could you attempt including `httpBasic` similar to `formLogin` in your `securityFilterChain` configuration and try?

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you intend to use only basic authentication in Spring Boot, consider replacing `.formLogin()` with `.httpBasic()` or adding it alongside if you wish to use both.

Here's the modified code:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("/health", "/api/v1/user/new").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/**").authenticated())
            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .build();
}
```